# How can I select FlowId with bigger CreateDate for each DetailId

Tags: sql-server

How can I select [FlowId] with bigger [CreateDate] for each [DetailId] 
for example detail data
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from t a
where dt = (select max(dt)
            from T b where a.detailid = b.detailid)
order by 1
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58882/2)

Comment: thank for your response. it have best performance ? or exist other way with better performance??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 and above, use a ranking function like [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
with TopFlow as
(
  select *
    , FlowRank = row_number() over (partition by DetailID
                                   order by [Date] desc, FlowID desc)
  from MyTable
)
select DetailID
  , FlowID
  , [Date]
from TopFlow
where FlowRank = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/419c1/5).

Answer (score 0):

```
select M.*
from MyTable M
inner join 
(
select DetailID,max(Date) Date
from MyTable
Group by DetailID
)T
on M.DetailID=T.DetailID
and M.Date=T.Date
order by M.DetailID
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3df10/3)**